# SQL Server 2005 Index Filter Feature

Tags: sql-server, indexing, indexed-view

I was told that there is new a feature in SQL Server 2005 called index filters.

What I want to do is add an Index to a column and have the index ignore null values.

I can't find good information on this feature (maybe my source is wrong). Can anyone provide additional information on this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_mycolumn ON mytable(mycolumn) WHERE mycolumn IS NOT NULL
```

This will work only in `SQL Server 2008`, though.

From [**the docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx):

> ```
> WHERE <filter_predicate>
> ```
>
> > Creates a filtered index by specifying which rows to include in the index. The filtered index must be a nonclustered index on a table. Creates filtered statistics for the data rows in the filtered index.

Comment: Filtered index is only available in 2008.

Comment: @James: and which year did I say?

Comment: Sorry. Might not have read your answer properly. My apologies;

Answer (score 7):

I think you are speaking about filtered indexes, which were introduced in SQL Server 2008, not 2005.

For information, have a look at this article: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Filtered_Indexes_in_SQL_Server_2008_p1.aspx

Or just do a google search for "sql server filtered indexes".